# java for loop executes extra iteration

Tags: java, for-loop

I am trying to execute the following code but get a null pointer on the add property method. I added system.out.println statements producing the second code listing with the resultant output. I am very confused. Both variables allProp and prop are define outside the routine and they are initialized

```
private static void addProperties(Properties prop) {

   String propertyValue = null;
   Set<String> propNames = prop.stringPropertyNames();
   String[] nameList = propNames.toArray(new String[15]);
   for (String propName:nameList) {
      propertyValue = prop.getProperty(propName);
       allProp.put(propName, propertyValue);
      loadOldValues(propName, propertyValue);
   }
}
```

This is the code with print statements.

```
    private static void addProperties(Properties prop) {

   String propertyValue = null;
   Set<String> propNames = prop.stringPropertyNames();
   String[] nameList = propNames.toArray(new String[15]);
   System.out.println("Number of properties "+Integer.toString(prop.size())+"  "+prop.toString());
   for (String propName:nameList) {
       System.out.println("properties name "+propName);
      propertyValue = prop.getProperty(propName);
       allProp.put(propName, propertyValue);
      loadOldValues(propName, propertyValue);
   }
   System.out.println("Done with routine");
}
```

And finally the output. I don't understand the 3rd iteration.

Number of properties 2  {myNewParm=RunOnce, appURL=http://192.168.200.16:9094/cta-cceds/  }
properties name appURL
properties name MynewParm
properties name null
e

Comment: Use `new String[0]` as argument, not 15.

Answer (score 2):

There's no need to create `nameList` as an array for this. You can iterate the `propNames` set directly:

```
private static void addProperties(Properties prop) {
    Set<String> propNames = prop.stringPropertyNames();
    for (String propName:  propNames) {
        String propertyValue = prop.getProperty(propName);
        allProp.put(propName, propertyValue);
        loadOldValues(propName, propertyValue);
    }
}
```

You might also be able to make use of [`allProp.putAll(prop)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#putAll-java.util.Map-) rather than iterating through the keys (though this might require restructuring `loadOldValues`).